# Laravel Homestead installation shared folder issue

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm trying to install the last laravel homestead.

After cloning the repo into ~/Homestead and launch vagrant up.

I have this error :

> ==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
>       homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/fboland/Homestead
>   Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
>   because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
>   made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
>   Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
>   guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
>   Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:
>
> mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the command was:

: No such file or directory

But the folder realy exists !
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Try launching homestead in an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VirtualBox 5.1.16 (the latest at the time of writing this), you will have to downgrade to VirtualBox 5.1.14 as there is an issue with the version of Guest Additions in this release.

More information in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/510

Answer (score 1):

Installing the vbguest plugin worked in my case with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and Vagrant 2.0.2:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```